# Torsion subgroup of the group $\prod_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abeliqn group. We call the torsion part of of $G$ the subgroup $T(G)=\{g \in G : g\text{ has finite order}\}$

According to L. Fuchs: The torsion subgroup of the group $G=\prod_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is $T(G)=\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

How can I show that ?

I tried to do it by proving that every element of $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is of finite order (i.e in the torsion subgroup), and every element of torsion is in $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Take an element $x \in \bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, which means $x$ has non-zero values in only finitely many components. Since each component is a cyclic group of prime order $p_i$, each non-zero coordinate $x_i$ has order $p_i$. As $x$ has non-zero values in only finitely many components, the order of $x$ is finite. Hence, every element in $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is in the torsion subgroup.

The other part is what I'm struggling with.

Comment: What progress have you made? Don’t just post and expect it to be done by us. Here’s a question for you to answer: Why is the answer not all of $G$?

Comment: The first subtlety is the difference between the direct product and the direct sum when taking over infinite indices. How is $T(G)$ different from $G$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your previous question was closed for lack of context. Please adapt to feedback.

Comment: WHy is not $G$. if we take  the element $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots)$ with $o(x_i)=p_i$, the ordrer of $x$ is the least common multiple of p_i with $i \in \mathbb{N}$  which does not exist.  Thus $x$ of infinite ordre

Comment: Edit your post to include that, rather than adding the comment. OK, so presumably you can show every element of the direct sum is a torsion element and that anything not in the direct sum is not torsion.

Comment: You seem to be going backwards. In your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710348/742) (which you posted multiple times) you asserted this fact as known.

Comment: an element $x\in G$ is of order $n$ if $nx_i=0$ for ALL $i$, this should help you see why you need a finite number of non-zero coordinates.